# How can I change the default download directory of downthemall from /root/Downloads/ to /home/user/Downloads/?

Tags: permissions, firefox, root, downloads

I'm having some trouble with the Downthemall addon for firefox on ubuntu. This addon puts the downloaded contents in `/root/Downloads/`, but it is very annoying to use the GUI to copy or edit those files while the user is not permitted to open that directory. How can I change that directory on Ubuntu 14.04? I want to change it to `/home/user/Downloads/`.

Comment: Are you running Firefox as root by any any chance? You should NEVER do that, but I think that is the only way how it could possibly save anything in /root.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I already solved this problem. By changing the directory while downloading an image from Facebook  using the Browse icon.   https://imgur.com/a/Jk3xV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in a very straightforward way:

1. right click on link you want to download
2. choose `save link with DownThemAll`
3. choose your specific destination in `save files in` field.